# How to add location points onto a shapefile imported into R from QGIS using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, qgis, r-sf

I'm working on a project which involves GPS coordinates from offshore locations. I'm looking to measure the distance from shore for each of my points. I have created a shapefile of the shoreline in question in QGIS and I have successfully imported it into R using the `st_read()` function (named "biminishore" in this example).
With the following code, I'm able to plot my shapefile in ggplot2:

```
bplot = ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = biminishore, size = 0.1, color = "black", fill = "green1") + 
  ggtitle("Bimini, The Bahamas")  +
  coord_sf() +
  theme_classic() 
plot(bplot)
```

Now, I would like to add the location coordinates (imported into R as a .csv with separate columns for Lat and Lon) as a layer over the imported shapefile. Can anyone suggest how to go about doing this in a way that will allow me to calculate the distance between each point and the nearest shoreline point?
My currents attempts are giving the error: `Error in st_transform.sfc(st_geometry(x), crs, ...) :  cannot transform sfc object with missing crs`

I assume this means my coordinate systems are incompatible but haven't found a way around this yet. So far, I have tried combining my point columns using `SpatialPoints()`. I've also tried using multiple forms of `st_set_crs()` and `st_transform()` but I haven't had any luck yet. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Read your points file as a csv & then transform it to an `sf` object:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)

points <- read_csv('path_to_points.csv')

#make it an sf object, change Long and Lat to the correct column name
points_sf <- st_as_sf(points, coords = c("Long", "Lat"))

# set crs of points_sf to same as biminishore object
points_sf <- st_set_crs(points_sf, st_crs(biminishore))
```

Then you should be able to plot them together by adding:

```
+ geom_sf(data = points_sf)
```

to your ggplot2 call.

Finding the nearest feature between the two can be done with `sf::st_nearest_feature(points_sf, biminishore)`.

A good post on nearest features & distances: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/349955/getting-a-new-column-with-distance-to-the-nearest-feature-in-r

Comment: Hi there, thanks so much for this @mrhellmann . Unfortunately, when I get to setting the crs, I am met with this error:  ```Error in st_set_crs(points_sf, crs = st_crs(biminishore)) : 
  unused argument (crs = st_crs(biminishore))```

Comment: Try st_set_crs(points_sf, value = st_crs(biminishore)) , I may have used the wrong argument name.

Comment: Nevermind, I ended up getting it to work using ```st_crs(points_sf) = st_crs(biminishore)``` Thanks for your help!